# How can i Remove consecutive duplicate tuples from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have list of tuples called lt.

```
lt = [ (1,2) , (1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4) , (5,6) , (7,8) , (7,8) ]
```

I want to remove all consecutive duplicate tuple from the list. The result should look like this.

```
mainList = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`pairwise()` function from the `itertools` reception section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

mainList = [curr for curr, next in pairwise(lt) if curr != next]
```

This gives you a new list with all consecutive tuples removed. You could also use the [`itertools.groupby()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with the default identity key:

```
from itertools import groupby

mainList = [k for k, g in groupby(lt)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, groupby
>>> lt = [ (1,2) , (1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4) , (5,6) , (7,8) , (7,8) ]
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)
...
>>> [curr for curr, next in pairwise(lt) if curr != next]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(lt)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lt = [ (1,2) , (1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4) , (5,6) , (7,8) , (7,8) ] 

mainList = []

for t in lt:
  if len(mainList) == 0:
    mainList.append(t)
  else:
    if mainList[-1] != t:
      mainList.append(t)

print(mainList)
```

**RESULT**

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an intricate list comprehension?

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(lt) if i == o or v != lt[i-1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to make a new list, and add the elements to that list. If an element is already in the new list, don't add it.

```
lt = [ (1,2) , (1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4) , (5,6) , (7,8) , (7,8) ] 
newlt = [lt[0]]
for item in range(len(lt)):
    if item == 0:
        continue
    elif lt[item] == lt[item - 1]:
        continue
    else:
        newlt.append(lt[item])
print(newlt)

[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Edit: New solution, this should work. It's clearly very basic.

Comment: Good attempt, but your code will produce inaccurate result. Try your code with this list. lt = [ (1,2) , (1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4) , (5,6) , (7,8) , (7,8) ,(1,2)] . index0 and 1 are consecutive duplicate but the last element is not. Your code will remove the last one too.